# How to execute a dynamic stored procedure that return a table in vb6 recordset and assign Datasource to a spreadgrid

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, vb6

I wrote a dynamic procedure than populate the columns and then use Pivot to show the data.
How to execute this procedure from vb6 and return the content as datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO for this, you will need to add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Ojects.  The code as I remember (long time since vb6) is something like

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim strConn As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCol1 As String
Dim strCol2 As String

strConn = "[YOUR CONNECTION SRING]" '(see www.connectionstrings.com for help)

conn.Open connStr

strSQL = "[YOUR SQL QUERY]" '(IE. Proc name)

rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Do While Not rs.EOF
    strCol1 = rs.Fields("Col1Name")
    strCol1 = rs.Fields("Col2Name")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

If conn.State = adStateOpen Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```